# Set php priority on execution

Tags: php, javascript

I have a problem, in php form I have two functions calls, one php function and another javascript one. These functions are called on a submit form. The php function is called on form submit and the javascript one is called "onclick" when the submit button is pressed.

How could I reach that javascript function will be executed before php function?

Comment: Use `onsubmit` event of form instead `onclick` event of button

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're saying the form posts to a PHP script, and a function in that script is called when you post. Try switching your Javascript function to the form's onsubmit event instead of the button's onclick. The function will execute first, and if it returns true, then the form will be submitted to the PHP script. If the function returns false, the form will not be submitted.

Comment: Okey, but the first function is window.frame.nameframe.namefunction();  that is javascript function that execute a form that after writes in a file.

Well, the second function should read the file.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, but the first function is window.frame.nameframe.namefunction();  that is javascript function that execute a form that after writes in a file.

Well, the second function should read the file.